# .htaccess language redirect to virtual folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-accept-language

I try to redirect to a virtual folder, if a specific language isnt detected, but this doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^!dk [NC] #if language isn't "dk"
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]                 # rewrite to folder
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]              # virtual folder
```

what i need:

if someone with another language than "dk" visits url.to/page.html he should be redirected to url.to/en/page.html, otherways he should stay in the root folder (url.to/page.html).

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another condition to your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^!dk [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?!en/).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```